# error is showing in my view codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a error on my view which I am trying to work out why but not know how to fix.

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> **Severity: Warning**
>
> **Message: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given**

What would be the best method to fix this I think it has something to do with my post `permission[access]` on controller that's effecting view.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Access Permission</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="well well-sm" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
<?php foreach ($permissions as $permission) { ?>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<?php if (in_array($permission, $access)) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[access][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" checked="checked" />
<?php echo $permission; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[access][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" />
<?php echo $permission; ?>
<?php } ?>
</label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);">Select All</a> / <a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);">Unselect All</a></div>
</div>
```

Controller Function

```
public function getForm() {
    $data['title'] = "Users Group";

    $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

    if (isset($id) && $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') != 'POST') {
        $user_group_info = $this->model_user_group->getUserGroup($id);
    }

    $ignore = array(
        'admin',
        'dashboard',
        'filemanager',
        'login',
        'menu',
        'register',
        'online',
        'customer_total',
        'user_total',
        'chart',
        'activity',
        'logout',
        'footer',
        'header'
    );

    $data['permissions'] = array();

    $files = glob(FCPATH . 'application/modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        //$part = explode('/', dirname($file));

        $permission =  basename(strtolower($file), '.php');

        if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
            $data['permissions'][] = $permission;
        }
    }

    if (null !==($this->input->post('permission[access]'))) {
        $data['access'] = $this->input->post('permission[access]');
    } elseif ($user_group_info['permission']['access']) {
        $data['access'] = $user_group_info['permission']['access'];
    } else {
        $data['access'] = array();
    }

    $this->load->view('template/user/users_group_form.tpl', $data);
}
```

Comment: `in_array($access, $permission)`. Needle first, haystack second : [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Check `$data['access']`. It returns `boolean`, should be `array()`

Comment: Can you give me examples please codeigniter post will not let me do `$this->input->post['permission']['access']` but can do this `$this->input->post('permission[access]')` I have another library which does but trying to make it work with codeigniter post

Comment: Dump `access` data before `load->view` like that `var_dump($data['access'])`. You will see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive the problem lies in your controller, like you initially said. Try this:

In your controller, replace this:

```
if (null !== $this->input->post('permission[access]')) {
    $data['access'] = $this->input->post('permission[access]');
} elseif ($user_group_info['permission']['access']) {
    $data['access'] = $user_group_info['permission']['access'];
} else {
    $data['access'] = array();
}
```

with this:

```
$permission_access = $this->input->post('permission');
if (isset($permission_access)) {
    if (isset($permission_access['access'])) {
        $data['access'] = $permission_access['access'];
    } elseif ($user_group_info['permission']['access']) {
        $data['access'] = $user_group_info['permission']['access'];
    } else {
        $data['access'] = array();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just testing but if I submit form and permission access is empty it throws error because no data present how can I get around that,

Comment: add a !empty to your conditional. I updated my answer

Comment: Tryed that still same `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: access
Filename: user/Users_group.php` and this  only shows up if all is empty when form submitted

Comment: hmm.. how about adding `is_array`? Check the update  for the second `if`

Comment: Problem solved I updated the your post with working version that lets you submit if empty. had to use isset

Comment: nice!, this is why i love SO.. we all teach other some things. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72579/discussion-between-mustang83-and-codegodie).